# Malware that destroys the color yellow?

Tags: malware, color

I have no idea where to turn with this, but I am worried that malware or other misbehaving software is causing a color distortion.  The story is:

- my phone, a Moto G5 Plus, at some point lost the ability to show the color yellow, rendering it instead as a sickly green. The screen overall lost a bit of "spark", becoming washed out and dull.  It was an old phone, and I decided to live with something I was pretty sure was a (rare, since I found no similar stories on the net) hardware issue.
- I then upgraded to a Mate 20 Pro, which surprisingly showed the same thing.  Since it was new, I returned it to the shop for repairs, and brought my old phone back to life.  The repairs took long enough that I managed to break my old phone's screen, order a new one, and replace it.  To my surprise, yellow was still missing after I changed the display.
- I finally got my new phone back, after a display change and factory reset, and now it's all good.

Thoughts:

- it seems very unlikely to me that the same obscure hardware error would occur to me twice.
- especially since the display technologies are very different, LCD vs AMOLED.
- the Mate was updated with all the magic of Android, so a number of apps and potentially data were automatically installed/transferred.
- after I got the Mate the second time, I accidentally logged in with the wrong account, so no automatic installation/recovery was performed.

It sounds unlikely, but is there malware or flawed software that could cause this?  Something that were transferred with in the recovery process the first time?  And if so, where can I report it?  Can anybody find accounts of similar experiences?  If it is a hardware fault, does it have a plausible explanation (it seems all of R,G, and B, are mostly intact, it's only yellow that turns green).

Comment: Yellow is the combination of red and green. Therefore if you see green instead of yellow the color red is missing. Have you made sure that this is really a smartphone and not a perception problem? (may be some sort of red-green color blindness).

Comment: While we don't want to expect for the worst, behind [this link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/31/Rainbow-gradient-fully-saturated.svg/500px-Rainbow-gradient-fully-saturated.svg.png) is a color of the rainbow. Next, there's a setting in Developer Options to simulate color space (i.e. color blindness), though we can't guess if you or someone else accidentally turned it on.

Comment: I did put my phone side-by-side with the same model in a shop, and checked all possible display settings together with staff to ensure they matched.  As a reference, I used the "Color mode & temperature settings" page, which includes a rainbow.  I found it very strange that only yellow appeared to be affected, the reds looked fine.

Anyway, the problem is solved for me, I mainly want to put the problem description out there, in case somebody else experience the same thing.